# GridViewColumn DataTemplate: context doesn't take from the ListView ItemSources

Tags: wpf, xaml, gridview, datatemplate

Within my `ListView`/`GridView`, properties for each of the items of the `ItemsSource` (of type `ObservableCollection<Changelog>`) are displaying correctly when using `DisplayMemberBinding` (and the IDE is showing the correct type, `ProjectRound` is indeed a property of `Changelog`).

However, when using this very simple `CellTemplate`, the 'row item' type is recognized as the type used in the `DataContext` of the whole `UserControl` that contains the `ListView`. And thus, the property is not found ("*Unable to resolve the property 'ProjectRound' in data context of type 'namespace.vm'*") , and ultimately not shown (both in the designer and at runtime).
Occurs with a `Label` as below, but also with a `Textblock` or an `Image` bound to a Bitmap property.

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Changelogs}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ProjectRound}" />
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Content="{Binding ProjectRound}" ></Label>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I tried setting the type in the `DataTemplate`:

```xml
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:Changelog}">
    <Label Content="{Binding ProjectRound}" ></Label>
</DataTemplate>
```

The IDE likes it better and doesn't complain that the property can't be found, but still doesn't display anything.

I've looked into `RelativeSource`, but to no avail

```xml
RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestoryType={x:Type Changelog}}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking about the XAML designer or does it not work at runtime?

Comment: Both, doesn't display in the designer, doesn't work at runtime.

Comment: What is the type of the ProjectRound property? How is it declared? Why are you using a Label instead of a TextBlock?

Comment: It's a string. `    public string ProjectRound
    {
        get => _projectRound;
        set
        {
            if (value == _projectRound) return;
            _projectRound = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }`

Comment: It's a label for no good reason, should be a textblock (same thing happens with a textblock though, or an image bound to a bitmap property).

Comment: From what you are showing here, your problem is not reproducible.

Comment: Yeah, I took this out of the app context in a brand new project, and I cannot repro myself. Setting the DataType was the solution once taken out of the app context.